# Splitting a very large string with a custom delimiter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to determine the word frequency in a column that is a `VARCHAR(3000)`. I am not sure if this is the best data type but the table creation was not in hand. In any case, I have been using the following function (taken from [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648)) to split strings up until this point:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split
(
    @RowData nvarchar(2000),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Data nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN 
    Declare @Cnt int
    Set @Cnt = 1

    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)
    Begin
        Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
        Select 
            Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))

        Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
        Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    End

    Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
    Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))

    Return
END
```

Usage was as follows:

```
SELECT s FROM dbo.Split(' ', @description)
```

It has been working very nicely but now I am getting an error:

> The statement terminated. The maximum
>   recursion 100 has been exhausted
>   before statement completion.

Does anyone have suggestions on what is a good way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. Just in case someone else faces the same problem, the following from [here](http://www.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx) works perfect on large strings:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitLarge(@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))     
as     
begin     
    declare @idx int     
    declare @slice varchar(8000)     

    select @idx = 1     
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return     

    while @idx!= 0     
    begin     
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)     
        if @idx!=0     
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)     
        else     
            set @slice = @String     

        if(len(@slice)>0)
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)     

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)     
        if len(@String) = 0 break     
    end 
return     
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This function [taken from here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/22/60213.aspx) uses .Nodes and avoids loops and recursive CTES

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@data NVARCHAR(MAX), @delimiter NVARCHAR(5))
RETURNS @t TABLE (data NVARCHAR(max))
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @textXML XML;
    SELECT    @textXML = CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(@data, @delimiter, '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML);

    INSERT INTO @t(data)
    SELECT  T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS data
    FROM    @textXML.nodes('/d') T(split)

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: I tested this against the accepted answer above that used loops and found this one performed much worse.  CPU and reads were far higher than the one with loops.  My tests used an input string with 100 and 200 data elements.  Does anyone have any ideas on when this would work better than the accepted answer?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg I realize your comment is in the context of this answer but you might want to consider asking this as a separate question. As an aside it's almost always a bad idea to split strings in SQL. A [CLR proc](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1665/sql-server-clr-and-sql-split-functions-to-parse-a-delimited-string/) is going to much faster. Another alternative is to use Table Valued Paramters

Answer (score 0):

I have a situation where the following code works well for me.  The code makes use of the replace function and SQL 2008's ability to insert multiple rows with a single insert statement.  The only drawback to this method, if it is really a drawback, is it is limited to 1000 splits.

```
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[StringSegmenter]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[StringSegmenter]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[StringSegmenter]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StringSegmenter](
    [ss_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ss_segment] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StringSegmenter] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ss_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

truncate table scratchpad.dbo.stringsegmenter
declare @String varchar(max)
declare @Splitter varchar(10)
set @String = '1,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,666666666666666666666666666666,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,666666666666666666666666666666,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,666666666666666666666666666666,2222222222222222222,3,4,55555555555555555555555,666666666666666666666666666666'
set @Splitter = ','
set @String = 'Insert [dbo].[StringSegmenter] Values (''' + replace(@string, @splitter,'''),(''') + ''')'
select @String
execute (@String)

Select * from [dbo].[StringSegmenter] order by ss_id
```