# Split string and save it to temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Table which is having a column with junk values

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(junkValues nvarchar(max))

INSERT into @tmp (junkValues)
VALUES ('@{''id''= ''63FCE3C0-B6FE-4FFE-8BC8-506A338455DD''; Value="ABC"; Other="ddd"}')

INSERT into @tmp (junkValues)
VALUES ('@{''id''= ''C10560BA-7059-4AC5-B9ED-77BAC7182BD7''; Other="ddd"; Value="XYZ" }')
```

I wanted to convert this semicolon separated value to another temporary table.

```
DECLARE @outputTempTable TABLE(CDID uniqueidentifier, Value nvarchar(max))
```

Where CDID will be the id from @tmp and Value will be Value from @tmp

Expecting an output like below

```
CDID                                       Value       
-----                                      -----------
63FCE3C0-B6FE-4FFE-8BC8-506A338455DD        ABC
C10560BA-7059-4AC5-B9ED-77BAC7182BD7        XYZ
```

I am using SQL Server 2008, is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Are these junkValues always have this size? I mean string length. If not, how large can they be?

Comment: Similar Question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460699/splitting-a-very-large-string-with-a-custom-delimiter?rq=1)

Comment: junkValues could be of any size..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit complex, but it Works!, please try following,

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(junkValues nvarchar(max))

INSERT into @tmp (junkValues)
VALUES ('@{''id''= ''63FCE3C0-B6FE-4FFE-8BC8-506A338455DD''; Value="ABC", Other="ddd"}')

INSERT into @tmp (junkValues)
VALUES ('@{''id''= ''C10560BA-7059-4AC5-B9ED-77BAC7182BD7''; Other="ddd"; Value="XYZ" }')

;with cte as
(
select junkValues
        ,CHARINDEX('''id''= ''',junkValues) + 7 as IDStart
        ,CHARINDEX(''';',junkValues,CHARINDEX('''id''= ''',junkValues))  as IDEnd
        ,CHARINDEX('Value="',junkValues) + 7 as valStart
        ,CHARINDEX('"',junkValues,CHARINDEX('Value="',junkValues) + 8)  as valEnd

from @tmp
)
select *
    ,SUBSTRING(junkValues,IDStart, IDEnd  - IDStart  )  as IDCol
    ,SUBSTRING(junkValues,valStart, valEnd  - valStart  )  as ValCol
    from cte
```

Comment: Damn you was faster than me! +1, this is it ;)

Comment: The position of 'value' is not predictable, I have updated the question. The above answer will not work in this case.

Comment: Ok. Wait will try more

Answer (score 1):

May this help you..

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(junkValues nvarchar(max))

INSERT into @tmp (junkValues)
VALUES ('@{''id''= ''63FCE3C0-B6FE-4FFE-8BC8-506A338455DD''; Value="ABC", Other="ddd"}')

INSERT into @tmp (junkValues)
VALUES ('@{''id''= ''C10560BA-7059-4AC5-B9ED-77BAC7182BD7''; Value="XYZ", Other="ddd"}')

SELECT 
SUBSTRING(junkValues,CHARINDEX('''= ''',junkValues)+4, 36) AS CDID,
SUBSTRING(junkValues,CHARINDEX('="',junkValues)+2,((CHARINDEX('", O',junkValues))-(CHARINDEX('="',junkValues)+2))) AS Value
from @tmp
```

Comment: This doesn't work as intended. And as @HashCoder wrote, the size of fields are variable

Comment: I think size will not make any problem until format is not altered.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's simplistic approach, but if the data is really laid out as in your sample, then this is the simplest and most efficient way:

```
select substring(junkValues, 10, 36) as CDID, substring(junkValues, 56, 3) as Value
from #tmp
```

Otherwise, one should use PATINDEX to identify start and length of substrings:

```
select 
substring(junkValues, patindex('%''id''= %', junkValues)+7, patindex('%; Value=%', junkValues)-11),
substring (junkValues, patindex('%Value=%', junkValues)+7, patindex('%Other=%', junkValues)-patindex('%Value=%', junkValues)-10)
from #tmp
```

Comment: As @HashCoder wrote, the size of fields are variable